# JavaScript Slide show with caption functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with my slide show, i created a slide show with js however, the caption i have those does not change with the pictures only the first one has the caption however all other pictures does not show any caption. Help me guys. thank you.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slide Show</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slide_show.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section>
    <h1>Dog Breed Slide Show</h1>
    <h2 id="caption">Afghan-Hound</h2>
    <img id="slide" src="images/dog0.jpg" alt="Afghan-Hound">
    <div id="slides"> 
        <img src="images/dog0.jpg">
        <img src="images/dog1.jpg" title="DOg MAn">
        <img src="images/dog2.jpg" alt="American-Eskimo">
        <img src="images/dog3.jpg" alt="French Bulldog">
        <img src="images/dog4.jpg" alt="German Shepard">
        <img src="images/dog5.jpg" alt="Italian-Greyhound">
        <img src="images/dog6.jpg" alt="Labrador Retriever">
        <img src="images/dog7.jpg" alt="Samoyed">
        <img src="images/dog8.jpg" alt="Siberian Husky">
        <img src="images/dog9.jpg" alt="Basset-Hound">
    </div>


    <div id="buttons">
        <input type="button" id="prev" value="Previous" onclick=showPrev()>
        <input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause" onclick=showStop()>
    <input type="button" id="play" value="play" onclick=showAuto()>
        <input type="button" id="next" value="Next" onclick=showNext()>         
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 380px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1, h2, ul, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    color: blue;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: .5em 0;
}
img {
    height: 250px;
}
#slides img {
    display: none;
}
#buttons {
    margin-top: .5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var curimage=0;
    var frequency=2000; 

    function showSlideNum()
    {
        document.getElementById('slides').value=curimage.alt;

    }

    function showNext()
        {
        curimage++;
        if (curimage>9)
            {curimage--;
            alert('This is last picture in the catalog');
        }
        document.images.slide.src='images/dog'+curimage+'.jpg';
        showSlideNum();
        }


    function showPrev()
        {
        curimage--;
        if (curimage<0)
            {curimage++;
        alert('There is no more picture before this one!!!');

            }
            document.images.slide.src='images/dog'+curimage+'.jpg';
            showSlideNum();
            }
    function clearImage()
        {
        curimage=0;
        showSlideNum();
        }
    function setfrequency(newFrequency)
    {
        frequency=newFrequency;
        alert(frequency);
    }

    function showAuto()
    {
    curimage++;
    if (curimage>9)
        {
        curimage=0
        }
    document.images.slide.src='images/dog'+curimage+'.jpg';
    showSlideNum();
    setTimeout('showAuto()', frequency);
    }

    function showStop()
    {
    document.location=document.location;
    }
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/143sayed/d7LyjmLg/4/#&togetherjs=FjdTRl0FTe

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working at all. Not even changing the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Object with all images.

Select element of title and add respectively value with: `$(elem).text(text)`

```js
$(function () {
  var images = {
    "0": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/250", "Afghan-Hound"],
    "1": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/260", "DOg MAn"],
    "2": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/270", "American-Eskimo"],
    "3": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/280", "French Bulldog"],
    "4": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/290", "German Shepard"],
    "5": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/300", "Italian-Greyhound"],
    "6": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/310", "Labrador Retriever"],
    "7": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/320", "Samoyed"],
    "8": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/330", "Siberian Husky"],
    "9": ["http://lorempixel.com/250/340", "Basset-Hound"]
  };
  var curimage = 0;

  function showSlide() {
    resume();
    $("#slide").attr("src", images[curimage][0]);
    $('#caption').text(images[curimage][1]);
  }

  function showNext(bool) {
    curimage += 1;
    if (curimage > 9) {
      curimage = 9;
      return;
    }
    showSlide();
  }

  function showPrev() {
    curimage -= 1;
    if (curimage < 0) {
      curimage = 0;
      return;
    }
    showSlide();
  }
  var frequency = 2000,
    pause,
    playing = false;

  function showAuto() {
    if (!playing) {
      playing = true;
      pause = setTimeout(function(){
        curimage+=1;
        if (curimage>9){
          curimage=0
        }
        showSlide();
      }, frequency);
    }
  }

  function showStop() {
    playing = false;
    clearTimeout(pause);
  }

  function resume() {
    if (playing) {
      showStop();
      showAuto();
    }
  }

  function clearImage() {
    curimage = 0;
    showSlide();
    clearTimeout(pause);
  }
  showSlide();
  $("#prev").click(showPrev);
  $("#pause").click(showStop);
  $("#play").click(showAuto);
  $("#next").click(showNext);
}());
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 380px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1, h2, ul, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    color: blue;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: .5em 0;
}
img {
    height: 250px;
}
#buttons {
    margin-top: .5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <h1>Dog Breed Slide Show</h1>
    <h2 id="caption">Afghan-Hound</h2>
    <img id="slide">
    <div id="buttons">
        <input type="button" id="prev" value="Previous">
        <input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause">
        <input type="button" id="play" value="play">
        <input type="button" id="next" value="Next">         
    </div>
</section>
```